# Format timestamp in JSON_TABLE COLUMNS

Tags: json, oracle

I have some JSON in an oracle table:

```
{"orders":[{"timestamp": "2016-08-10T06:15:00.4"}]}
```

And using JSON_TABLE to select/create a view:

```
SELECT jt.*
FROM table1
JSON_TABLE (table1.json_data, '$.orders[*]' ERROR ON ERROR
COLUMNS ( StartTime TIMESTAMP PATH '$.timestamp')) AS jt;
```

However no matter what format I put the date/time in JSON I always get:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
> string

Is there a way to format the json, or something I am missing? If i pass in a date like "2016-08-10", then it will successfully create a DATE column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 18c, your query also works (if you add in `CROSS JOIN`, `CROSS APPLY` or a comma, for a legacy cross join after `table1`) and change `$.timeStamp` to lower case.

However, if you can't get it working in Oracle 12c then you can get the string value and use `TO_TIMESTAMP` to convert it:

```sql
SELECT StartTime,
       TO_TIMESTAMP( StartTime_Str, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF9' )
         AS StartTime_FromStr
FROM   table1
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         table1.json_data,
         '$.orders[*]'
         ERROR ON ERROR
         COLUMNS (
           StartTime     TIMESTAMP    PATH '$.timestamp',
           StartTime_Str VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.timestamp'
         )
       ) jt;
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( json_data VARCHAR2(4000) CHECK ( json_data IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO table1 ( json_data )
  VALUES ( '{"orders":[{"timestamp": "2016-08-10T06:15:00.4"}]}' );
```

This outputs:

> ```
> STARTTIME                 | STARTTIME_FROMSTR           
> :------------------------ | :---------------------------
> 10-AUG-16 06.15.00.400000 | 10-AUG-16 06.15.00.400000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cbc1d02744e2981a3cc6c2c7abd791e3)*

Comment: Thanks a lot - the to_timestamp solution works fine. The timeStamp was a typo - i updated original post to timestamp!

Answer (score 1):

When running your query on my Oracle 19.6.0.0.0 database, I do not have any problem parsing your example (see below). If you are on an older version of Oracle, it may help to apply the latest patch set.  You also might have to parse it out as a string, then use `TO_DATE` based on the format of the date you are receiving.

```
SQL> SELECT jt.*
  2    FROM (SELECT '{"orders":[{"timestamp": "2016-08-10T06:15:00.4"}]}' AS json_data FROM DUAL) table1,
  3         JSON_TABLE (table1.json_data,
  4                     '$.orders[*]'
  5                     ERROR ON ERROR
  6                     COLUMNS (StartTime TIMESTAMP PATH '$.timestamp')) AS jt;


                         STARTTIME
__________________________________
10-AUG-16 06.15.00.400000000 AM
```

Comment: Thanks for checking - I am using older 12.1 so that may explain the difference. I guess I can create the column as VARCHAR an put a view on this view which does a TO_DATE.